# How to detect in Tkinter that whole window is moved (esspecially to the other screen)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, dpi

I want to change scaling depend on screen. I know how to scale but I do not know how to detect that windows is move from screen 1 to screen 2.

What event and bind is need for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I have to disappointing you, there is no such binding to detect that. There is however a long history of trying to get a cross platform specific solution working, without fully success. You can read something about it in the [tcler's-wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Dual+or+Multiple+Monitors) where I have the basic idea from.

The only way to track your window by moving is by a binding to `'<Configure>'`, this event is fired when you move the window. Within a event-handler you can track the position with `event.root_x` and `event.root_y`. These coordinates are screencoordinates from the window. So far so good, we can know when we are moving and where we are.

A useful insight is that the first screen, most often the left one, has always the coordinate `0,0` as the upper left corner. Place your window there with `window.geometry('+0+0')` ensure the window is placed there via `window.update_idletasks()` ask for `wm_maxsize`, that is the width and height of the current screen and usually used to *zoom* your window. The next thing you have to do is a little bit of math against `winfo_screenwidth()` and `winfo_screenheight()` that usually gives you all the available space on the screen.

**EDIT:** Also try `winfo_vrootwidth()` and `winfo_vrootheight()`

There you have it, you know where the second screen begins and how to track the window movement. I think you are good to go with that and try it out, but **keep in mind that this technique is not OS-independent**.

An additional thought that I had was to invoke that procedure in a loop and to *search* for more screens, but never actual coded it.
Pro tip: when you do `window.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0)` you don't have to watch your window jumping around by gathering the needed information.